# Django - How to write unit test checking if ValidationError was raised by ModelForm clean() for ManyToMany relationship?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have ManyToMany field in my model and I wrote a custom validation for it in forms ModelForm created only in this purpose. The validation works fine, but I don't know how to write unit test for it correctly.

```
#models.py

class Course(models.Model):
    # some code
    max_number_of_students = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        default=30)

class ClassOccurrence(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
    # some code
```

```
# forms.py

class ClassOccurrenceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # some code

    def clean(self):
        # Checks if number of students inscribed is not greater than allowed
        # for the course
        cleaned_data = super(ClassOccurrenceForm, self).clean()
        students = cleaned_data.get('students')
        course = cleaned_data.get('course')
        if students and course:
            if students.count() > course.max_number_of_students:
                raise ValidationError({
                    'students': "Too many students!})
        return cleaned_data
```

The problem is with this part:

```
# tests.py

    # some code
    def test_clean_number_of_students_smaller_than_max_students_number(self):        
        self.course_0.max_number_of_students = 5
        self.course_0.save()
        users = UserFactory.create_batch(10)
        self.assertRaises(ValidationError, self.class_occurrence_0.students.add(*users))      
        try:
            self.class_occurrence_0.students.add(*users)                
        except ValidationError as e:
            self.assertEqual(e.errors, {'students': ["Too many students!"]})
```

Currently it doesn't work as intended. It seems in test method the ValidationError is not raised where it should be raised. Does anybody can help me to fix it?

Comment: I can't see why you think the error would be raised here. Firstly, forms catch ValidationErrors internally and use them to populate the form errors. But secondly, *you are not even using the form in your test*.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you for the hint! I'm Django beginner. Now I use form and it seems to be ok. However it's strange for me that I had to define 'course' in arguments, as it was already specified for instance `form = ClassOccurrenceForm({'students':[*users], 'course': self.course_0.pk}, instance=self.class_occurrence_0)` Is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

So this seems to work:

```
    #tests.py
    def test_clean_number_of_students_smaller_than_max_students_number(self):
        '''Check if number of students is not bigger than maximum number'''
        self.course_0.max_number_of_students = 5
        self.course_0.save()
        users = UserFactory.create_batch(10)
        form = ClassOccurrenceForm(
            {'students':[*users], 'course': self.course_0.pk}, 
            instance=self.class_occurrence_0
        )
        self.assertEqual(form.errors, 
            {'students': ["Too many students!"]})
```